# when the list plot is triggered by an array of files, using PlotRange gives "Iterator does not have appropriate bounds"

Tags: mathematical-optimization

So basically I have 21 plots, each one looks like[image]

Now, I want to replot this from 200 to 500 only, here's what I did:

```
In[8]:= data = Table[Import[name[[i, j]]], {i, 1, 21}, {j, 1, 51}];
        Dimensions[data[[1,1]]]
        {499,2}

In[12]:= Table[ListPlot[data[[i]]], {i, 1, 21}, PlotRegion -> {{150, 500}, {0.050, 0.060}}]
```

Then I received the error `Iterator {PlotRegion->{{150,500},{0.05,0.06}}} does not have appropriate bounds.`
I checked the `>>` error cause, it seems the iteration bound is not a real number and so cannot be reached using the default step size. Much appreciated if some can give me a hint?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure whether you want 21 data sets plotted in one plot or 21 plots, but you've got `Table[ListPlot[], {i, 1, 21}, PlotRegion ->...]` and the `PlotRegion ->...` is being passed to `Table[]` in the position of an iterator (like `{i, 1, 21}`).  You might want `Table[ListPlot[..,  PlotRange ->..], {i, 1, 21}]`, if you want 21 separate plots.

Comment: Ah, I see the mistake I made, `PlotRegion/PlotRange` must be within the `ListPlot`, thanks for pinpointing it out!

Comment: I want 21 plots, but that can be easily obtained by using `Table`, `ln[8]` was basically to import each individual files, as I have 21*50 files and I want  to plot 21 graphs with 50 data sets each, that's how I got the diagram in the question, hope the explanation is clear. And thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Michael for pinpointing out the trivial mistake

```
In[12]:= Table[ListPlot[data[[i]],, PlotRegion -> {{150, 500}, {0.050, 0.060}}], {i, 1, 21}]
```

shall solve the issue.